# Ways to solve numerically differential equations in C

Tags: numerical-analysis, ode, c

I have to solve numerically a differential equation in C. The equation is:

[image]

How can I write some code to solve it? Are there some numerical methods (Runge-Kutta maybe?) to solve it?

A colleague proposed to me to use the exact discretization method, but I don't think it's the smartest way to do, especially in programming.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This question is too broad to answer in a generally useful way and doesn't really show any effort to answer it on your own. Assuming that h and u are constants in your equation then it easily can easily be solved analytically.

Comment: To answer your questions: "How can I write some code to solve it?" Find the method you want to use and start coding. "Are there some numerical methods (Runge-Kutta maybe?) to solve it?" Yes, there are many, RK is one. "Any suggestions?" Read up on numerical solutions to first order ODEs.

Comment: One thing you can try is reading the wikipedia page on Runge-Kutta and try implementing yourself based on the explanation on wikipedia. I did this on the past and was very intructive.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the easiest way is to use the Forward Euler method. You should take a look at [this](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Euler_method#C.2B.2B) page in which the code is explained.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use C++, I suggest taking a look at the odeint package that
is part of the Boost library:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/numeric/odeint/doc/html/index.html

In general, writing a production quality ODE solver is not a simple task. odeint has been available in Boost for several years and is relatively mature and robust. Pre-built Boost libraries are available for many platforms which significantly simplifies installation.

Comment: unfortunately I need to use C